# Nano seconds convertion to hours and minutes

Tags: singlestore

How can I convert the Nano seconds to hours and munutes format.  The below query is not working properly.

select date_format(timestamp_ns,"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%N") from information_schema.mv_sysinfo_mem;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the from_unixtime builtin to convert from a unix timestamp in seconds to a formatted date. This builtin also expects the input to have units of seconds while timestamp_ns has units of nanoseconds. So the following should work for you

```
select from_unixtime(timestamp_ns/1000/1000/1000) 
from information_schema.mv_sysinfo_mem
```